# Solve the recurrence using the Substitution method

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I need to prove a tight bound on the following recurrence using the Substitution method:

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) +\frac{n}{\log(n)}$

I have arrived to the "guess" part of the Substitution method and know that $T(n)$ is $O(n\log(\log(n)))$ by using recursion tree and iteration method. But I have trouble figuring out how to proceed from the inductive step both for big-$O$ and Omega:

Assume  $T(n/2) <= cn\log(\log(n))$

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + \frac{n}{\log(n)} \leq 2cn\log(\log(n)) + \frac{n}{\log(n)}$

Assume  $T(n/2) \geq cn\log(\log(n))$

$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/\log(n)\geq 2cn\log(\log(n)) + \frac{n}{\log(n)}$

Comment: No. You should assume $T(k)\leq ck \log\log k$ for all $k<n$, and then show that you still have $T(n)\leq cn \log\log n$ (where in this case, you will use the induction hypothesis (IH) for $k=\frac{n}{2}$). Here, your IH is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I won't get here in the usual details about this recurrence relations, and the fact that there are floors/ceilings implicitly assumed or to take care of for them to make sense. Your lecturer must have taken care of that.*

To get you started, the upper bound. (I assumeyou will deal with the base cases, as one should in a proof by induction). In what follows, $c\geq \log_2 e$ is an absolute constant. I will also assume this is from a computer science setting, so $\log=\log_2$.

At step $n$, you have the following induction hypothesis:
$$
\forall k < n,\qquad T(k) \leq ck\log\log k \tag{IH}
$$
Then, using our recurrent relation:
$$
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n}{\log n} \\
&\leq 2c\frac{n}{2}\log\log\frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{\log n} \tag{by IH}\\
&= c n \log(\log n -1 )+ \frac{n}{\log n} \\
&= cn \log\left(\log n\left(1-\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right)+ \frac{n}{\log n} \\
&= cn \log\log n + cn \log \left(1-\frac{1}{\log n}\right)+ \frac{n}{\log n} \\
&\leq cn \log\log n - cn \cdot \frac{1}{\log_2 e} \frac{1}{\log n}+ \frac{n}{\log n} \tag{$\ast$}\\
&= cn \log\log n - \frac{c}{\log_2 e}\frac{n}{\log n}+ \frac{n}{\log n} \\
&\leq cn \log\log n
\end{align}
$$
were for $(\ast)$ we used the inequality $\ln(1-x)\leq -x$, and in the end the fact that $c\geq \log_2 e$. This concludes the induction.

Comment: Erm. Before accepting, have you read it carefully and made sure you understood everything (and everything looked correct)?

Comment: Yes, thank you, this was indeed helpful. I was stuck on the third step, now it's clear. I had actually tried simplifying the logarithm of difference but couldn't proceed from there .

Comment: Glad that helped, then!